# Basic php question

Tags: php, html

New to php. Can anyone tell me what this means?

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit']) || $Email!=$ConfirmEmail || !$info_str || !$valid_email)
```

Comment: This is amazingly basic. I recommend you buy a "Learn to Program PHP" type book and get reading.

Comment: Completely changing the question after it has already received 4 answers != cool.

Answer (score 5):

```
IF
There is no element named 'submit' in the _POST array
OR
if $Email is not equal to $ConfirmEmail
OR
$info_str is empty
OR
$valid_email is zero

then do something...mostly split an error to the user.
```

Effectively it does error checking, ensuring the request has come through a form submit, has a valid email that matches the confirm email and has a non empty $info_str variable value.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bunch of checks to see if certain variables/post fields aren't set, or if the Email and ConfirmEmail variables don't match.

Broken down into pieces:

```
if(                             < IF
    !isset($_POST['submit'])    < NOT (IS SET (POST FIELD 'submit'))
    ||                          < OR
    $Email!=$ConfirmEmail       < VARIABLE 'Email' IS NOT EQUAL TO VARIABLE 'ConfirmEmail'
    ||                          < OR
    !$info_str                  < NOT (VARIABLE 'info_str' IS A TRUE VALUE)
    ||                          < OR
    !$valid_email               < NOT (VARIABLE 'valid_email' IS A TRUE VALUE)
)
```

Note that due to the `!` "nots", many of the conditions are actually the opposite of what they would otherwise be (i.e. positive test if `$valid_email` is actually a *false* value - such as being `null`).

Answer (score 0):

It is form validator. If form is submitted and email equal predefined email, and other variables are defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (                          // if
    !isset($_POST['submit'])  // 'submit' element in $_POST array is not set
    ||                        // or
    $Email != $ConfirmEmail   // $Email does not equal $ConfirmEmail
    ||                        // or
    !$info_str                // $info_str is false
    ||                        // or
    !$valid_email             // $valid_email is false
)
```

`!` *negates* a value. `'foo'` would usually be regarded as `true`, the negated `!'foo'` is `false`. `''` (an empty string) is usually regarded as `false`, the negated `!''` is `true`. See [PHP type comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) and [Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

Answer (score 0):

I just needed rearrange the constructs to solve my problem.

Comment: Please roll back the question to its original state, since right now the answers don't make any sense and won't serve any future reader as reference. Then, open a new question for your new problem. Also, please leave answer for answers, not clarifications to questions. :)